# I am doing socket program and not able to receive msg from client side

Tags: c++, sockets

//this is  Server side code ,I m using onReceive after connecting to server

```
//void CMFCExampleDlg::OnReceive(int nErrorCode)
{   
  recv(clientsocket,"200" , 1024, 0);
  m_name.SetVariable("gear","1");
}
```

//////client side

```
//BOOL CMFCClientDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
  if(pMsg->lParam==VK_NUMLOCK)
    send(s,"200",1024,0);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two obvious mistakes:

- the use of [`recv()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

  ```
  recv(clientsocket,"200" , 1024, 0);
  ```

the second argument is populated with incoming data so must be modifiable (modifying a string literal is undefined behaviour) and large enough to store the requested bytes:

```
    char buffer[1024] = ""; /* recv() does not null terminate. */
    int bytes_read = recv(clientsocket, buffer , 1024, 0);

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytes_read)
    {
        /* Failure. */
    }
    else
    {
        /* SOME bytes were read. */
    }
```

- the code is lying to [`send()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as there is not `1024` bytes of data to be sent:

  ```
  send(s,"200",1024,0);
  ```

this will result in undefined behaviour as `send()` will be accessing beyond the bounds of the array where the string literal `"200"` is stored:

```
    int bytes_sent = send(s, "200", 3, 0);
    if (3 != bytes_sent)
    {
        /* Failed to send all data. */
    }
```

It is important to remember that writing and reading data to and from a socket is just a stream of bytes and has no logical concept of a message: you have to implement that via an application defined protocol of some sort. For example:

- prefixing each message with its length in bytes followed by the mesasge content, or
- terminating each message with a new-line character

`recv()` and `send()` are typically used in a loop until all data is read, all data is sent or an irrecoverable failure occurs.